# Why webpack commonChunk duplicates packages between my bundles?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I want to create a `vendor.bundle.js` from my modules.
I configured webpack:

```
...
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/index.js'],
    vendor: [
      'axios',
      'lodash',
      'recharts',
      'moment',
      ......
      'react-select',
      'react-tooltip',
      'react-toggle',
      'buffer',
      'jstz',
      'pikaday',
      'qrcode-js',
      'notie',
      'tippy.js',
      'react-dropzone',
      'react-dd-menu',
      'html-to-draftjs',
      'react-virtualized',
      'react-draft-wysiwyg',
      'js-search',
      'qr.js'
    ]
  },
  ...
  output: {
    path: '/Users/ben/pro/qbpanel2.0/qbpanel-2.0/qbpanel/app/assets/javascripts',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  ...
  plugins: [
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerPort: 9998
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
      path: '/Users/ben/pro/qbpanel2.0/qbpanel-2.0/qbpanel/app/assets/javascripts',
      publicPath: '/',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
...
  ]
}
```

I expect to see all the packages listed in `entry.vendor` to end in the `vendor.bundle.js`, and for most of them it happens, but in my some of them show up in both `bundle.js` and `vendor.bundle.js` files.

Why?

`bundle.js` I was not expecting to find `tippy.js` or `react-virtualized` or `lodash`
[image: bundle.js]
`vendor.bundle.js`, there are the same packages that are in the `bundle.js` and I expect to be only here.
[image: vendor.bundle.js]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of webpack are you using ?
To do what you're looking for, you can use the [commonsChunkPluggin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/)

The configuration could look like something like this in webpack 2:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['node-modules'],
    minChunks(module) {
      const context = module.context;
      return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
    },
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['vendor'],
    chunks: ['node-modules'],
    minChunks(module) {
      return module.context && /.*\/axios|losash|allTheModulesYouWant.*/.test(module.context);
    },
  }),
]
```

This creates a chunk with all the node modules and takes out of it some of them (that you need to name) to put them into vendor